# svn info - get revision of current working copy in PHP

Tags: php, svn

I'm using svn 1.8 locally, but the project is used by dozens of clients and they're using svn 1.6 (by dev request mostly).

The code currently used is the following:

```
$rev = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/.svn/entries", FILE_TEXT, null, 0, 20);
$rev = explode("\n", $rev);
$rev = $rev[3];
```

Obviously, this is a very inflexible solution that is bound to the file structure of SVN, which has already changed on Windows versions of SVN 1.8 (and, iirc, 1.7 too).

I want to use the following:

```
$rev = 0;
// $rootDir is the absolute path to the project root
exec('svn info ' . $rootDir, $output);

foreach ($output as $line)
{
    if (substr($line, 0, 8) === 'Revision')
    {
        $parts = explode(':', $line);
        $rev = intval(trim($parts[1]));
    }
}
// $rev should now contain the current revision of working copy
```

The code works fine, but I was told that executing `svn info` was "too slow", which is why the first approach was used. To me it seems that executing `svn info` takes a few milliseconds at most, so I don't see the problem. **Is there anything in my code that could cause problems?**

Also, **is it enough to just execute `svn info` on project root, or do I need to pass `-R` to it for correct results?**

Edit: ah, apparently some of the most newbie clients use TortoiseSVN which for some reason overrides default svn commands and runs the GUI instead of the expected stuff. Is there a way to detect this and use the old approach if that is the case?

Comment: Why PHP on developer's side instead of native SVN-tools?

Comment: TortoiseSVN **does not** override anything for CLI-side

Comment: @LazyBadger - the website that checks this revision does it on every page view, it outputs the revision at the page footer. It obviously could be improved by just reading the revision from the database, where it would be updated on every system updated, but at the moment i'm just trying to make the thing work as it is.

Comment: 1. In order to do *something* in TortoiseSVN's GUI from command-line, `TortoiseProc /command ...` must be executed. In Windows it's hard blindly build such aliases for `svn command` 2. If "revision in footer" needed for site, developed with SVN, not for interface to repository (such as WebSVN), you have (must?) to build static-string (once, on deploy to site), which show this data - and in easiest case it will be just `svnversion` output, but `subwcrev` possibilities seem more promising

Comment: @LazyBadger - that's what I'm talking about, TortoiseSVN requires using completely different commands for that stuff. And I know that the current way of outputting the revision is crap, I'm planning to change that in the nearest future anyway. And `subwcrev` is another Tortoise-specific thing, I'm not going to use that. Ever.

Comment: `svnversion > version.txt` ???

Comment: @LazyBadger - jesus christ, I'm not asking how to get the current revision, read the questions in my post. `The ones that end with a question mark.`

Answer (score -1):

```
function getRevision($dir){
    $rev = 0;
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        $path = $dir .'/' .  $file;
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        if($file == '.svn'){
            if(file_exists($path . '/entries')){
                $data = file($path . '/entries');
                $v = (int)$data[3];
                if($v > $rev)
                    $rev = $v;
            }
        }
        elseif(is_dir($path)){
            $v = getRevision($path);
            if($v > $rev)
                $rev = $v;
        }
    }
    return $rev;
}
```

its not the right way to get a version by svn info, if you have 2 different workspaces you need to know which one has which revision.
with this function you get the heighest revision of all files in a folder (and subfolders).

Comment: You must be joking. That's a performance killer for large projects (and is generally just bad). Also, the svn revision checker in my code is called on every page view (it's a terribly written system, not just in this regard), so this is obviously a terrible idea.

Comment: Not to mention this does not answer any of my questions. And what do you mean `its not the right way to get a version by svn info`, that is the proper way to get it. I don't have 2 different workspaces, and in my use case it wouldn't matter if I did.

Comment: this is your case that you havn't run 2 versions of your project. other developers do this. And if you dont known about build procedures where you can update a central text file (or database entry) with the new version, its also your fault!

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project ... this is the right way. If someone ask a question like yours, he wants to get "jokes", and then flaming the helping community... great one, NOT!

Comment: You have no idea what my or my co-workers' working environment is, and you're trying to answer questions that nobody asked. I know how the versions SHOULD be stored, but I'm not allowed to change that, so do me a favor and gtfo.